# How do I start a Windows program with spaces in the path from Perl?

Tags: perl, winapi

If I do:

```
my program = "C:\\MyPath\\MyProg.exe";
system(("start", $program));
```

MyProg starts up just fine and my script resumes after the system() command.  But if there are spaces in the path like

```
my program = "C:\\My Path\\MyProg.exe";
system(("start", $program));
```

It seems to run cmd, not MyProg.

I've tried quoting with things like:

```
my program = "C:\\My Path\\MyProg.exe";
system(("start", '"' . $program . '"'));
```

But nothing seems to help.

Of course I can get around it with fork() but I'd like to understand why I can't pass a path with spaces as an argument.

Comment: I'm skeptical that this works with double quotes and single backslashes.

Comment: You're right.  I dropped the extra backslash when I sanitized my example.  Sorry.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the built-in `start` command is a bit weird when it comes to quotes. You can reproduce this on the command line with `start "C:\My Path\MyProg.exe"` and see the same result. To properly execute it you need a set of empty quotes before it: `start "" "C:\My Path\MyProg.exe"`.

So your end result should be:

```
my program = "C:\\My Path\\MyProg.exe";
system('start "" "' . $program . '"');
```

**Edited** to include the suggesstion from ikegami. My perl is a bit rusty as I haven't used it in years.

Comment: There is no such thing as start.exe on NT, on Win9x you had start.exe, on NT it is a built-in command in cmd.exe

Comment: @Anders: Thanks, I remember back in the day when it was start.exe :)

Comment: @Chris Nelson, `system(("start", '"" "' . $program . '"'));` works, but only because `system` is buggy in Windows. `system('start "" "' . $program . '"');` or `system(qq{start "" "$program"});` would be better. `system('start', '', $program)` should work too, but I don't risk it with start's weirdness.

Comment: Thanks.  I needed to double my backslashes but 'start "" "' . $program . '"' works great.

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
my program = "C:/\"My Path\"/MyProg.exe";
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an perl expert but I found the following link.

http://bytes.com/topic/perl/answers/697488-problem-system-command-windows